# Display image fields of a node as slideshow

Tags: 6, media, javascript, views

I have created a content type with some text and image fields. I want to display its images as a slideshow below text fields in view node page of this content type. How can I do it ? Is view slideshow module suitable for this purpose ? or I have to use other module ?

I am working in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to anyone answered me. I solved my problem with Lightbox2 module. It adds a new option in 'display fields' of content type field management.

Answer (score 4):

[Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) should be *more* than enough for what you need.

**EDIT**

I meant [View field](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield), not Views Field View - sorry.

> Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
>   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial video for D6 setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcGoU1o87mI)

Comment: Follow the setup hd, theres quite a bit to do :-/

Comment: Should I create two views?

Comment: You shouldn't have to.  You should just be able to hide the images on the View mode of the node, and then display the slideshow either in a block below it, render it in your template, or use the other module I've listed.

Comment: how can I set images of each node in its viewfield when the node information is entered by user? (user uploaded images within add node page)

Comment: In your slideshow you just tell it to display those fields.  I'm not 100% sure what you're asking.

Comment: Slideshow makes all of it as a slide but I just want to display uploaded images in that node as slideshow not all of it.

Comment: Have you got your View set to show nodes or fields?

Comment: I set it to show Nodes.

Comment: Change it to fields and select the image field you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Views slideshow is probably the answer but a lot of people struggle with its setup so you might want to follow this http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7

Comment: thank you Alex. but I am using Drupal 6. Would you give me a link for 6 ?

Comment: Asker clearly states he is using D6 - this post is for D7.

Comment: Oops, slight oversight ;-) just wanted to let you know a guide to setting this up is required, well done Chapabu.

Comment: Easily done :)  Would be useful to leave it in case anyone on D7 sees this post though!